# Hall effect: Do the charges that build up on the sides of conductor kept in uniform magnetic field get uniformly distributed?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, voltage, hall-effect

When we keep a metal block through which some constant current is flowing in a uniform magnetic field the charges will separate and a potential difference will be created b/w the sides of the conductor. This is a case of [Hall effect](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hall_effect).

In trying to find quantitative relations the [book](https://archive.org/details/physicsforscient0000serw/page/826/mode/2up?view=theater) writes $\Delta V_h=E_hd$ (see equation $29.19$), but on what basis? The book didn't clear whether the charge that builds up on the sides (I will call them induced charges) is uniformly distributed or not$^*$. The book didn't mention b/w what points the voltage $\Delta V_h$ is defined for? Clearly, the book assumes that the field is uniform and hence $\Delta V_h$ is voltage for any two points on the sides. So is the induced charge uniformly distributed or not? If so then why?

[image]

Note: $*$ See equation 5 of this [pdf](http://courses.washington.edu/phys431/hall_effect/hall_effect.pdf) and read the [wiki article](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hall_effect#Theory).

Comment: Can you please explain why it should not be? Just to understand your reasoning around it and what makes you doubt it.
Every electron is subject to the same deflection due to the Lorentz force, thus I do not see any reason why the electric field generated should not be uniform.

Comment: What do you mean by charges being uniform?

Comment: By that, I mean charges are uniformly distributed over the surface.

Comment: What about their collision with atoms and other electrons? But still, if we ignore that, how exactly is it deducible that field will be uniform from the fact that Lorentz force is the same on each electron?

Answer (score 0):

Even if the charge were uniform on the narrow  'side faces' of the slab, this would give a field that was stronger nearer these sides than in the middle of the slab; it would not correspond to a uniform transverse electric field in the slab. This is because the geometry is very far from what it would need to be for such a correspondence: charged surfaces much closer together than their linear dimensions, as in an ideal parallel plate capacitor.

The proper justification for claiming uniform transverse $\vec E$ is the (assumed) uniformity of $\vec B$, and of the drift velocity, $\vec v$, because at every point in the slab  in the steady state, $\vec v \times \vec B = -\vec E_{\text{trans}}$ (the condition for no net transverse force on a charge-carrier).

Introductory textbooks do, in my experience, give the false impression that the uniform electric field arises just from a uniform distribution of charge on the side faces. There will certainly be charge separation as a result of the magnetic field, but working out the actual steady charge distribution on and inside the slab would be difficult. Fortunately we don't need to know it in order to derive the basic Hall voltage equation; all we need is $\vec E_{\text{trans}}$.